# Ping two ethernet card on the same computer and on the same subnet

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, ping

I have two NIC Ethernet card (eth1 and eth2) on the same computer (linux)  connected by a cross cable.

The two interfaces are on the same subnet :

```
eth1 : 192.168.200.1 255.255.255.0 

eth2 : 192.168.200.2 255.255.255.0
```

Then i add a route for each interface :

```
route add -net 192.168.200.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth1 

route add -net 192.168.200.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth2
```

Finally,i'm trying to ping :

```
ping 192.168.200.1 -I eth2 or ping 192.168.200.2 -I eth1
```

Ping command reaches error : Destination Host Unreachable

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-r` to the ping command?

Comment: Are the interfaces UP?

Comment: Yes both interface are up and i also try option -r on the ping command.But unfortunately ping reach same error.

Comment: Why did you specify a route? Are you using a subnet that is configured elsewhere within your network?

Comment: Did you run the route commands as root? Are those ping commands separate, as in, `ping 192.168.200.1 -I eth2`, then you ran `ping 192.168.200.2 -I eth1`, not `ping 192.168.200.1 -I eth2 or ping 192.168.200.2 -I eth1`? Try running ping like this `ping -I eth1 192.168.200.2`.

Comment: I need root privileges to run route commands and when i run ping like ping @IP -I interface or like ping -I interface @IP, ping commands reach same error.

Comment: Try this instead `route add -host 192.168.200.1 eth1` and `route add -host 192.168.200.2 eth2`

Comment: Heyn emb1995 i try our command but same error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, i use two virtual machine.
And i can ping eth1 or eth2, with eth2 or eth1.

Thank you,all for yours comments and help.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when u ping from your system, the source IP is set to INADDR_ANY. And when the kernel finds the destination IP to be on the same system, it will simply loopback it. Its using **loopback (lo)** interface.